# PySpark - How to do split on multiple dictionary values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After some processing on raw data I got my result as bellow , its like a Key with multiple values and the values are dictionary values - I want to make as Key + each dictionary values

```
[('HOMICIDE', {'2017': 1}), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', {'2015': 2, '2017': 2, '2016': 8}), 
('ROBBERY', {'2016': 2}), 
('OTHER OFFENSE', {'2016': 3}), 
('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', {'2017': 2, '2016': 2})]
```

How can I make the above to

```
('HOMICIDE', '2017': 1),
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2015': 2 ), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2017': 2,), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2016': 8), 
('ROBBERY', '2016': 2), 
('OTHER OFFENSE', '2016': 3), 
('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', '2017': 2)
('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', '2016': 2)]
```

Whether I need to move the dictionary to a List and from there I need to process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `flatMapValues`:

```
In [1]: rdd = sc.parallelize([('HOMICIDE', {'2017': 1}), 
   ...: ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', {'2015': 2, '2017': 2, '2016': 8}), 
   ...: ('ROBBERY', {'2016': 2}), 
   ...: ('OTHER OFFENSE', {'2016': 3}), 
   ...: ('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', {'2017': 2, '2016': 2})])

In [4]: rdd.flatMapValues(dict.items)
Out[4]: PythonRDD[5] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48

In [5]: rdd.flatMapValues(dict.items).collect()
Out[5]: 
[('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 2)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 2)),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2016', 8)),
 ('ROBBERY', ('2016', 2)),
 ('OTHER OFFENSE', ('2016', 3)),
 ('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', ('2017', 2)),
 ('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', ('2016', 2))]
```

or in a long way

```
In [5]: rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], k, v) for k, v in x[1].items()]).collect()
Out[5]:                                                                         
[('HOMICIDE', '2017', 1),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2015', 2),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2017', 2),
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2016', 8),
 ('ROBBERY', '2016', 2),
 ('OTHER OFFENSE', '2016', 3),
 ('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', '2017', 2),
 ('MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT', '2016', 2)]
```

Comment: I tried to execute
rdd.flatMapValues(dict.items).collect() 
but getting error as bellow - Let me check again, is there any other issue 
File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle method_descriptor objects

Comment: Instead of rdd.flatMapValues(dict.items).collect()  when I gave the bellow it got worked
 
>>   rdd.flatMapValues(lambda data: data.items()).collect()

Answer (score 0):

The bellow got worked - 
rdd.flatMapValues(lambda data: data.items()).collect()

Thanks to @StackPointer and @user8119199